# Adminlte sidebar treeview not opening items/sidebar not closing

Tags: angular, menu, treeview, adminlte

So, im working in a plataform and im using Angular and AdminLTE. After logging into the dashboard, my treeview menu doesnt work. Looks like it only works when i change li class to nav-item menu-open from the browser. I'm not getting any errors in the console

Please help, im getting crazy with this.

This is angular.json imports :

```
"styles": [
                            "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.css",
                            "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.js"
                        ]
```

This is my index.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Add AdminLTE 3.2 CSS files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/admin-lte@3.2.0/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/dist/css/adminlte.min.css?v=3.2.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css">
</head>

<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/dist/js/adminlte.js?v=3.2.0"></script>
    <script src="./assets/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried to initializethe treeview in ngOnInit $('[data-widget="treeview"]').Treeview('init');

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.